# How to correctly set up multi-language websites in NextJs for SEO? (avoid duplicate content)

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, internationalization, localization, next.js

I will have 5 websites, so 5 different domains

- .lt
- .com
- .lv
- .et
- .ru

Each of them will be translated in all the other languages using subfolders system offered by Next.

```
- example.lt
- example.lt/en 
- example.lt/lv 
- example.lt/et 
- example.lt/ru

- example.com
- example.com/lt
- example.com/lv
- example.com/et
- example.com/ru

and so on for other domains...
```

and the same for all the other domains.

When opening "example.lt/en" what should be the canonical URL? Should it be "example.com" which is in English? Or should it be "example.lt/en"?

So my question is how to correctly set canonical URLs and correctly use the "hreflang" property in order to avoid duplicate content in this case?

Will "example.lt/lv" and "example.com/lv" be considered duplicate content since they will have the same exact content? If yes, how to avoid that?

Comment: Why you are using 25 (5 x 5) URL combinations when you can either use single TLD with 5 language folders or 5 TLDs one for each language?

Comment: The payment methods available for one locale might not be the same as another locale in the same TLD. And I don't want users to be redirected to a different TLD to pay, as they might think they are purchasing from a different country. So I want to have a full set of locales and translations for each TLD